# Embedded terminal sending ESC on OS X

Tags: intellij-idea

I've made a fresh install of intellij after switching to v2016.1 and I noticed that I could not write the pipe character `|` anymore in the embedded terminal.

So I ran `cat` to see exactly what was going on, and it turns out that when using the `alt` key, the `ESC` character is prepended:

```
$ cat # type alt+shift+l
^[|
```

So I wonder if there is a (new?) option somewhere I might not be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a known issue of 2016.1 versions: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152291